# CSS Selector For Content Crawler (Finding Category Post URL)

Tags: css

code

```
div title="xxxx" class= "xxx"
a href = "/xx/xxx"
div class = "xx"
```

there are multiple of these codes, trying to pull al the "a href" links from them. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Why isn't that HTML?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your a tag to be child tag of div tag of class **'xxx'**

`<div title="xxxx" class= "xxx">
    <a href = "/xx/xxx">
    <div class = "xx">`

your css namespace would be

> .xxx a{  your css properties  }

if your anchor tag is not a child tag of div and it lies on the same level

> .xxx+a {  your css properties  }